# Reuse .sdf using different mesh files

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Say I have an sdf file like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.4">
    <model name="bookertshelf">
      <static>true</static>
      <link name="body">
        <visual name="visual">
          <geometry>
            <mesh><uri>model://bookertshelf/dummy.dae</uri></mesh>
          </geometry>
        </visual>
      </link>
    </model>
</sdf>
```

I have bookertshelf-%X%.dae files for all of which I like to use the same SDF config above. Is there a way to reuse this SDF file without doubling the file?

In my world file I tried the following that doesn't seem to be doing what I want (without error on console).

```
<include>
  <name>bookertshelf1</name>
  <pose>0 -6.0 0 1.5708 0 -1.5708</pose>
  <static>true</static>
  <uri>model://bookshelf</uri>
  <mesh><uri>model://bookertshelf/bookertshelf1.dae</uri></mesh>
</include>
```

I'm on Ubuntu Trusty, Gazebo 2.2.5. Upper version of Gazebo can't be an option since I'm using ROS Indigo where [2.2 seems like a must](http://answers.ros.org/question/208334/gazebo-version-collides-between-indigo-and-jade/?answer=210561#post-id-210561).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8958/reuse-.sdf-using-different-mesh-files/) by [IsaacS](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/15/isaacs/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 118 on 2015-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You could use erb to automatically generate your SDF as in [this](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/src/74a580447dd670bc78f9f9e476a6d5d3ffd69563/cart_front_steer/model.rsdf?at=default) example.

You would need a file, named for example `meshes.world.erb`, similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<%
  mesh_list = ["mesh0.dae", "mesh1.dae", "mesh2.dae"]
%>
<sdf version="1.4">
  <world name="default">
    <% # Loop through list
      i = 0
      mesh_list.each do |m|
        name = 'model_' + i.to_s
        i = i + 1
    %>
      <%= "<model name='#{name}'>" %>
        <static>true</static>
        <link name="body">
          <visual name="visual">
            <geometry>
              <mesh><uri><%= "model://bookertshelf/" + m %></uri></mesh>
            </geometry>
          </visual>
        </link>
      </model>
    <% end %>
  </world>
</sdf>
```

Then use erb to generate the world file (which I called `meshes.world`), from the command line:

```
erb meshes.world.erb > meshes.world
```

Then open the world on gazebo:

```
gazebo meshes.world
```

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2015-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [IsaacS](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/15/isaacs/) on 2015-07-03**:
Thanks. Originally I was hoping for a way to "reuse" a single SDF, not replicating SDF files, but after having seen discussions at another places (e.g. [this](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7213/parameterizing-elements-of-an-sdf-model/)) I now understand using erb is the best available option for SDF.